# How use android navigation with master->detail presentations?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, navigation

I use Android Arch Navigation in my project. For phones it's simple, but for tablets I  don't understand how use it. I have 2 nested graphs in one common graph, first is master and second is detail screen. How can I change detail from master graph?

I have been reading and watching Android tutorials on Code Lab and Udacity, but Google do not have the information.

Comment: Post some useful code and about graph library

Comment: I had a similar doubt when nav arch components were released. i came across this https://proandroiddev.com/master-detail-views-with-navigation-components-a20405f31974 recently which should help you.

Comment: i did ask ian lake about this long time back on his talk by commenting on youtube. he said there is space to improve documentation and there was a issue open regarding this. I think it would have been taken care off by now.